# wxWidgets/C++/Code::Blocks: Failed to import font from system library

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I've been making a simple app in C++/wxWidgets that just has a catalog of Garfield comix from the Internet, without the annoying ads and offers. (Don't ask me how I got access to the PNG files of each comic in the first place, because my name already explains that)

Anyway, I'm trying to make a static text with a specific font (in my case, that would be Tahoma size 8. I'm going to make it bold but for sake of simplicity I haven't done it yet). I use the following line of code to import it from the Windows internal font catalog:

```cpp
wxFont *CC_FONT_Tahoma_Bold(8, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, false, wxT("Tahoma"), wxFONTENCODING_DEFAULT);
```

but whenever I try that it just fails and gives the following error message (I'm using mingw-w64 8.1.0 if that helps):

> error: cannot convert 'wxFontEncoding' to 'wxFont*' in initialization

I have no idea what this means and I have tried to change the font encoding to every possible value, but still no progress. Also, I am creating the font in the App's OnInit function. I have **also** tried to put it in a different function. Please help.

Comment: For the formatting question: \`\`\`c++ before and ``` after but that did not change anything. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Show the contents of your `CC_FONT_Tahoma_Bold` function. It is probably returning the wrong thing.

Comment: @catalin what do you mean? It's just a wxFont object, not a function. My app's OnInit returns true.

Comment: Then you'd have to change it to one of these: `wxFont CC_FONT_Tahoma_Bold(8, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, false, wxT("Tahoma"), wxFONTENCODING_DEFAULT);` or `wxFont *CC_FONT_Tahoma_Bold = new wxFont(8, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, false, wxT("Tahoma"), wxFONTENCODING_DEFAULT);`

Comment: as mentioned above either create the font on the stack (preferably) or on the heap.

Comment: @catalin I am such a dumbo. I forgot to specify the "new wxFont" thingy, and now it works perfectly. Thanks.  Turns out it was just a silly mistake 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I just made a silly mistake.

The real code I should have used is:

```cpp
wxFont *CC_FONT_Tahoma_Bold = new wxFont(8, wxFONTFAMILY_SWISS, wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wxFONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, false, wxT("Tahoma"), wxFONTENCODING_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: don't forget to delete thatt object.

Comment: That’s a good point, in a regular case. However the reason that this font is named the lengthy name is so that it can be used throughout my application without creating and deleting things. Good thought though. 

Comment: this is a resource you allocated and u will have to delete it, otherwise you will have memory leak. It doesn't matter when u will do it...

Comment: Got it. The 300mb memory mystery has been solved.